# Can Field of fractions be Algebraically Closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let R be an integral domain which isn't a field.

> Can it be the case that the field of fractions is algebraically closed?

The reason I'm asking this is : The field of fractions of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Q$ which isn't algebraically closed.

One algebraic closure is C.

> Is $\mathbb C$ the field of fractions of some non field integral domain?

Comment: The ring of algebraic integers?

Comment: The ring of alg integers in C? Its field of fractions will also be C? Oh thanks!

Comment: Not quite. The field of fractions of the ring of algebraic integers will be the field of algebraic numbers in $\Bbb{C}$, which is algebraically closed (but contains no transcendental numbers).

Comment: Alright! What about my second question then?

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I would guess that you need to go through a Zorn's lemma argument when looking for a proper subring $D$ of $\Bbb{C}$ such that $\Bbb{C}$ would be the field of fractions of $D$. In fact, I'm not sure that my first guess for such a $D$ works :-/

Comment: That guess is: Let $S$ be a transcendence basis of $\Bbb{C}/\Bbb{Q}$. Then let $D$ be the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}[S]$ in $\Bbb{C}$. Many things to check, and I don't trust this. At least not yet.

Comment: I was thinking that the "required" integral domain can't be between R and C and also it can't be inside R (else we don't get i by taking fractions). Hence... ?

Comment: The field $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{C}_p$ which is the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then the completion of the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain whose quotient field is $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. But it is not an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ since not all of its elements are algebraic over the rationals